How to allow resizing TD smaller than the content by setting width on the TH?
I made a table with resizable columns. I am setting the width on the th element. But looks like it won't allow me to set width below the width of the longest td.
What I want to do is to allow the columns to resize to a minimum value.
What worked in allowing the td to be smaller than the content was to set max-width, however I don't want to have a max-width. And if I recall correctly, min-width doesn't work on tables.
Do I have anything to do about it? Or in this case it's better to try and create a table using CSS Grid instead?
My goal is to allow resizing the columns lower than the th and td content and show ellipsis instead (with ...)


activateTableResize();

function activateTableResize() {
  let table, tableContainer, resizeable, currentResizeBar, currentTh, tableFirstRow, tableRect, currentResizeBarRect;
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest('.resize-bar')) {
      resizeable = true;
      currentResizeBar = event.target;
      currentTh = event.target.closest('th');
      table = document.getElementById('my-table');
      tableContainer = document.getElementById('my-table-container');
      tableFirstRow = table.querySelector('tbody tr');
      tableRect = tableContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      currentResizeBarRect = currentResizeBar.getBoundingClientRect();
      document.querySelector("body").style.cursor = "col-resize";
      document.querySelector("body").style.userSelect = "none";
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    if (resizeable) {
      if (event.clientX + 5 < tableContainer.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
        let distanceMoved = event.clientX - currentTh.getBoundingClientRect().x;
        currentTh.style.width = `${distanceMoved}px`;
      }
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
    document.querySelector("body").style.cursor = "default";
    document.querySelector("body").style.userSelect = "default";
    resizeable = false;
  });
}
#my-table-container {}

#my-table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#my-table thead {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(140 140 140);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(140 140 140);
}

#my-table th {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#my-table th:first-child {
  width: 150px;
}

#my-table th .resize-bar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

#my-table tbody td div.cell-container,
#my-table thead th div.cell-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
<div id="my-table-container">
  <table id="my-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="cell-container">Name<span class="resize-bar"><span></div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="cell-container">Type<span class="resize-bar"><span></div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="cell-container">Size<span class="resize-bar"></span></div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">James Smith</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">20</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">jsmith@example.com</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">Jane Doe</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">19</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">jdoe@example.com</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>





Make .cell-container absolute and td,th relative positioned
Set height and line-height of td,th
Move the resize span outside of .cell-container (so it wouldn't be cut)



activateTableResize();

function activateTableResize() {
  let table, tableContainer, resizeable, currentResizeBar, currentTh, tableFirstRow, tableRect, currentResizeBarRect;
  document.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest('.resize-bar')) {
      resizeable = true;
      currentResizeBar = event.target;
      currentTh = event.target.closest('th');
      table = document.getElementById('my-table');
      tableContainer = document.getElementById('my-table-container');
      tableFirstRow = table.querySelector('tbody tr');
      tableRect = tableContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
      currentResizeBarRect = currentResizeBar.getBoundingClientRect();
      document.querySelector("body").style.cursor = "col-resize";
      document.querySelector("body").style.userSelect = "none";
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    if (resizeable) {
      if (event.clientX + 5 < tableContainer.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
        let distanceMoved = event.clientX - currentTh.getBoundingClientRect().x;
        currentTh.style.width = `${distanceMoved}px`;
      }
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", (event) => {
    document.querySelector("body").style.cursor = "default";
    document.querySelector("body").style.userSelect = "default";
    resizeable = false;
  });
}
#my-table-container {}

#my-table {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#my-table thead {
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(140 140 140);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(140 140 140);
}

#my-table th {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#my-table th:first-child {
  width: 150px;
}

#my-table th .resize-bar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

#my-table tbody td div.cell-container,
#my-table thead th div.cell-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 6px);
}

#my-table thead th{
  min-width: 50px;
}

#my-table thead th,
#my-table tbody td {
  position: relative;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
<div id="my-table-container">
  <table id="my-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">
          <div class="cell-container">Full Name</div><span class="resize-bar"><span></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="cell-container">Type</div><span class="resize-bar"><span></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="cell-container">Size</div><span class="resize-bar"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">James Smith</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">20</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">jsmith@example.com</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">Jane Doe</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">19</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="cell-container">jdoe@example.com</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




thank you, it is working. Now I have other JavaScript related bugs but I'll try to work them out. Btw, why did 1) and 2) fixed the issue? (I mean making it absolute and setting height)

@pileup it allows to resize th,td freely, and .cell-container doesn't interfere, just adjusting itself to the cells

got it! thanks. Would you recommend leaving it as is, or if you had to design it from scratch you would change something? And also - do you think I should keep the HTML table or Grid might work better here?

@pileup <table> is ok imho, i would make a table generator from data, or/and adding resize bars and wrapping into .cell-container automatically so you could transform a usual <table> into a resizable one

What do you mean by table generator from data? You mean dynamically creating it with JS? And one more thing regarding your solution which I couldn't figure - why does the right-most cell seem to have extra border to the top-right of it? Is it possible to make the last resize bar same width as the table?

@pileup, yes, dynamically. i don't see any extra border ‍♂️

Thank you and oh, my bad, I forgot to also change the html :)
